# UITextField not registering any text length in function

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I've initialized two `UITextField`s, `tf` and `tf1`. When the view loads, I want the text of the two fields to be `_minPrice` and `_maxPrice`, respectively. These are two NSString properties that are getting their values from a previous ViewController. When the present ViewController loads, it shows the correct values, so I know this part is working properly.

I want users to be able to edit the content of `tf` and `tf1`, so that whatever is contained in those two `UITextField` is used as the parameters in the `editMatchCenter` function below, whether that be the default string from `_minPrice` and `_maxPrice`, or whatever text the user enters in place of that. Editing the fields works fine, but when I press the submit button to run `editMatchCenter`, nothing happens, which tells me that **self.tf.text** and **self.tf1.text** are empty for some reason.

I've tried commenting out the if statement, and I get a crash stating:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'`

which refers to `@"minPrice": self.tf.text`.

**Text field initialization:**

```
        // Min Price
        UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 125, 70, 30)];
        [self.view addSubview:tf];

        tf.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        tf.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        tf.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue" size:14];
        tf.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        tf.text = _minPrice;

        // Max Price
        UITextField *tf1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195, 125, 70, 30)];
        [self.view addSubview:tf1];

        tf1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        tf1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        tf1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue" size:14];
        tf1.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
        tf1.text = _maxPrice;
```

**Submit button function:**

```
- (IBAction)submitButton:(id)sender
    {
        if (self.tf.text.length > 0 && self.tf1.text.length > 0) {

            [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"editMatchCenter"
                               withParameters:@{
                                                @"searchTerm": _searchTerm,
                                                @"minPrice": self.tf.text,
                                                @"maxPrice": self.tf1.text,
                                                @"itemCondition": _itemCondition,
                                                @"itemLocation": _itemLocation
                                                }
                                        block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {

                                            if (!error) {
                                                NSLog(@"Result: '%@'", result);
                                                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                                            }
                                        }];
        }
    }
```

**Properties from header:**

```
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *minPrice;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *maxPrice;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *itemCondition;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *itemLocation;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *searchTerm;

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tf;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *tf1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get nil is because you never initialised your properties. Instead you create new pointers in your code (tf and tf1).

Try replacing tf with self.tf and tf1 with self.tf1. Like this:

```
self.tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 125, 70, 30)];

self.tf1 = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(195, 125, 70, 30)];
```